# Encoding a probability distribution for a genetic algorithm

Tags: encoding, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

What are some simple and efficient ways to encode a probability distribution as a chromosome for a genetic/evolutionary algorithm?

Comment: You need to be more specific on what is you plan. What do you want to optimize, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It highly depends on the nature of the probability distribution you have in hand. As you know, a probability distribution is a mathematical function. Therefore, the properties of this function govern the representation of the probability distribution as a chromosome. For example, do you have a discrete probability distribution (which is encoded by a discrete list of the probabilities of the outcomes like tossing a coin) or a continuous probability distribution (which is applicable when the set of possible outcomes can take on values in a continuous range like the temperature on a given day).
As a simple instance, consider that you want to encode Normal distribution which is an important distribution in probability theory. This distrubution can be encoded as a two-dimensional chromosome in which the first dimension is the mean (Mu) and variance (Sigma^2). You can then calculate the probability using these two parameters. For other continuous probability distribution like Cauchy, you can follow the similar way.